# How to fill iteratively a list with arrays in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have an empty list `my_list=[]` and I want to iteratively add arrays to this list. Suppose my arrays are `[1,2,3]`, `[4,5,6]`, `[7,8,9]`,`[10,11,12]`, I want to have a list such that `my_list=[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12]]` such that each element of the list is an array.

Comment: Can't you just add the lists to `my_list`? Doesn't that do what you need?

Comment: How do you get the arrays? from user input?

Comment: Also;  list and array are same in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `append`. Sample example assuming you have four variables storing the arrays/lists to add to the list

```
my_list=[] 
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = [7,8,9]
d = [10,11,12]

my_list.append(a)
my_list.append(b)
my_list.append(c)
my_list.append(d)

# [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

If you want some iterative solution, use the following list comprehension way. Although here finally `my_list` and `arrays` are the same.

```
arrays = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12]]

my_list = [i for i in arrays]
```

If you don't prefer list comprehension

```
my_list = []
for i in arrays:
    my_list.append(i)
```

**NumPy way** : One of the possible solutions using `append`

```
arrays = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12]])
my_list = np.empty((0,len(arrays[0])))

for arr in arrays:
    my_list = np.append(my_list, [arr], axis=0)
```

Another way using `vstack` where 3 in `(0,3)` correspond to the number of columns (length of a single list).

```
my_list = np.array([]).reshape(0,3)

for arr in arrays:
    my_list = np.vstack((my_list, arr))
```

Comment: `my_list = arrays[:]` :) Not iterative though!

Comment: @iGian: True that. I thought OP wants iterative solution, one at a time. What you wrote is basically cloning a list

Comment: Thank you ! Actually, I was doing stuff with np.append and it was concatenating all things, losing the array structure. Is it possible to work np.append too to solve my problem ?

Comment: @MysteryGuy: Wait for the numpy solution. I will update in a minute

Comment: @MysteryGuy: I added the numpy solution.